# Usefulness of post-incrementing a weakly_incrementable?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I studied the [`weakly_incrementable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/weakly_incrementable) concept recently and I am wondering what the post-increment operator is good for, given that the concept does not define any requirements for the result of the operation.

Is it actually okay to return `void` for `operator++(int)`?

```
void operator++(int) { ++(*this); }
```

It seems in line with the other requirements of the concept (like that it does not have to be copyable) and also with the fact that the `incrementable` concept introduces requirements that make `i++` useful, but in that case I am wondering why `i++` is defined by the concept at all. After all, when you require something to implement the `weakly_incrementable` concept, you can always use `++i` instead of `i++` because

1. you can't rely on `i++` having any useful properties, apart from those already provided by `++i` but
2. `i++` may be more inefficient (when it creates a copy of the iterator, for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That design decission is documented in [P0541](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0541r1.html).

> Is it actually okay to return `void` for `operator++(int)`?

Yes. It is. A specific straw poll was taken, as stated in the paper.

Removing the postfix increment in its entirety was also considered but:

> The authors of the Ranges TS strongly prefer keeping the postfix
> increment operator for input iterators. Consider the following fairly
> common (anti-)pattern:
>
> ```
> for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); i++) {
> // ...
> }
> ```
>
> Aside from concerns over the cost of post-increment, there is nothing wrong with this code per se, and the authors see no
> compelling reason to break it. And by permitting `i++` to return `void`,
> we would actually be mitigating the performance problem.